Iterate through all tr in html using selenium library in python
<table class="flush-table sticky-table" id="myTable">
    <thead class="sticky-thead">
     <tr>
      <th>A Number</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>Pkts</th>
      <th>ID1</th>
      <th>ID2</th>
      <th>Type1</th>
      <th>Type2</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0 days, 20h:55m:18s</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>cast</td>
      <td>Mul</td>
      <td>5.0</td>
      <td>5.0</td>
      <td>160.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0 days, 20h:55m:18s</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Un</td>
      <td>Mu</td>
      <td>5.0</td>
      <td>5.0</td>
      <td>160.0</td>
    </tr>
   </thead>
  </table>

table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//thead[@class = 'sticky-thead']")
print(table.text)

for row in table.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//tr"):
    print(row.text)
    print([td.text for td in row.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//td")])

If i run this script, the elements "A B Pkts ID1 ID2 Type1 Type2 C D E"(i.e. Table header) is captured in list. However the i could not capture table data. Please help me to understand how can i capture the table data as well.

This would make sense if your code would contain ".//th" instead of ".//td".

XPATH is an absolute path and is being used only once. You need to first find all th tags and then all remaining tr tags.
cols = table.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
print([th.text for th in cols.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "th")])

for row in table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")[1:]:  # Skip first
    print([td.text for td in row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")])

Which results to:
['A Number', 'B', 'Pkts', 'ID1', 'ID2', 'Type1', 'Type2', 'C', 'D', 'E']
['1', '0 days, 20h:55m:18s', '0', '5', '7', 'cast', 'Mul', '5.0', '5.0', '160.0']
['2', '0 days, 20h:55m:18s', '0', '6', '9', 'Un', 'Mu', '5.0', '5.0', '160.0']

